# Replace all characters except expression using gsub only

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Given strings:

```
smple_paths <- c("/path/path/path/abc22/path/path",
                 "/apath/apath/paath/abc11/something/path")
```

I would like to replace all characters excluding phrase `abc\\d{2}`

## Attempt

```
gsub(
    pattern = "(?!abc\\d{2})",
    replacement = "",
    x = smple_paths,
    perl = TRUE
)

# [1] "/path/path/path/abc22/path/path"        
# [2] "/apath/apath/paath/abc11/something/path"
```

### Desired results

```
abc22
abc11
```

## Notes

- I'm not looking for [`stringr::str_extract`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.3.1/topics/str_extract) based solution or any other solution not based on `gsub`

Comment: Does it mean you want to extract `abc\\d{2}`? [`regmatches(smple_paths, gregexpr("abc\\d{2}", smple_paths))`](https://ideone.com/2jsJCX)? Why *replacing*?

Comment: Well, why not something simpler like [`sub("^.*/(abc\\d{2})(?:/.*)?$", "\\1", smple_paths)`](https://ideone.com/JDMjZ0)?

Comment: Yes but as in notes it has to go into `gsub` syntax.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you care to make `sub` comment an answer I will happily accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not care about the `abc\d{2}` context, you may use

```
sub(".*(abc\\d{2}).*", "\\1", smple_paths)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/azqmCq/1) and [this R demo](https://ideone.com/QX1ei0).

If you care about the context, you may match and capture `abc` + 2 digits after `/` and before `/` or end  of the string, while matching any text before and after this pattern using

```
 sub("^.*/(abc\\d{2})(?:/.*)?$", "\\1", smple_paths)
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/JDMjZ0) and a [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gx57qE/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string (not necessary here, but kept for the sake of clarity)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(abc\\d{2})` - Group 1: `abc` and 2 digits
- `(?:/.*)?` - an optional (1 or 0) occurrence of a `/` followed with any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

The `\1` placeholder in the replacement pattern inserts the captured text back into the result.